# Cycle for matching values in a string

Tags: python, pandas, loops

how to write a loop if the value of `df['Country'] = df['Country1']`, then the value of the `geometry` column that corresponded to `df['Country1']` is overwritten

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: You don't need a loop when you're using pandas dataframes.

Comment: You should join the dataframe with itself to find the rows wehre `Country = Country1`.

Comment: What if df["country"] not in df["country1"], you should not change the value of this row, right?